# Internet Explorer, jQuery and contenteditable + focusout / blur not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I'm having a div with the contenteditable attribute set to true. I need an event, when the user leaves the editable field.

That  works fine on chrome/firefox but IE11 doesn't trigger the event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#editable").focusout(function(e) {
        $("#debug").html($("#debug").html() + "focusout ");
    });
    $("#editable").blur(function(e) {
        $("#debug").html($("#debug").html() + "blur ");
    });
});
```

I'm on jQuery 1.10.1 - here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5J8kq/

UPDATE: found the answer. I was doing this on a contenteditable A-tag which doesn't seem to work on IE. Changing this to a DIV or SPAN tag works just fine.
That did cost me 4h...

Comment: Please check Jquery 1.10.1 is loaded in IE. Because I am getting `$` is undefined.

Comment: Here your issue is just regarding how jsFiddle wraps code in iframe and how IE handles it regarding jQuery 1.10.1, see still using jQuery 1.10.1 but code not wrapped in iframe, it works on IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/5J8kq/show/ I'm not sure exactly from where comes from this bug

Comment: Thanks, Wolff. That works for the jsFiddle - but the same code in my application still failes. I'm rather stumped right now...

I'm trying to implement this in an jQuery UI Widget which has something like

    label.focusout(e) {
        // do something here - never called in IE11
    }

Where label is a local variable in a jQueryUI Widget method...